# Flux: common practices to separate actions btw action creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

If you'll look at [flux-chat](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat) example you may see three action creators. Pretty much for such small hello-world app. I'm writting React+Flux application and wondering *what is the common practice for bigger apps to separate actions between action creators?* Should I create the only one or create separate for each module? If I will create the separate for each module - than they will depend among each others, isthat acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Action creators should all be on the same level of abstraction, meaning they should never depend on each other (notice that none of them depend on each other here: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat/js/actions).  And while action creators shouldn't depend on each other, they can depend on multiple stores, and multiple actions can depend on the same store.  This is what separates actions from action creators since the actions are really defined inside of a store.  So if you need to access data from more than one store, you can do that in an action creator (They use the thread store in the message store, and that's bad practice.  The thread data should be passed into the action rather than included via the store).

In the flux chat example, they have another concept called Utils (very general) which doesn't emit events or do anything to the application state.  In fact, it doesn't really add to the flux architecture.  It is just a concept born out of the DRY principle.

EDIT:

The reason why action creators depend on stores is because it is a separation in abstraction that specifies where logic belongs.  As an analogy, you wouldn't be worrying about allocating memory when working on a function that is meant for addition of two integers.  You want to only have the relevant code pertaining to the calculation, and delegate low level details to other methods.  This is the same difference in abstraction that the stores and actions are providing.  Actions are working to connect separate services/stores together, while stores maintain how to interact with http, websockets, and application state.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! May you provide more arguments why action creators should depend on Stores? Also `ChatMessageActionCreators` calls `ChatWebAPIUtils.createMessage(message)` which in turn invoke `ChatServerActionCreators`'s method. Isn't it dependencies  between action creators? I will very appreciate if you provide some examples of how it should be, and why it would be worse in another way

Comment: The only reason why it calls the ChatServerActionCreators is to simulate a server success.  Otherwise, that wouldn't be needed. @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk I updated the answer to add more arguments why action creators depend on stores.